# Django: Group by and return multiple fields

Tags: django, django-models, group-by, django-orm

In Django, Consider the following model class,

```py
class Report(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Owner,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='data',
    )
    balance = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    report_date = models.DateField()
```

Assume this table has only the following four items,

```py
<QuerySet [{'owner': 1, 'balance': 100, 'report_date': datetime.date(2023, 3, 4)}, {'owner': 1, 'balance': 50, 'report_date': datetime.date(2023, 3, 9)}, {'owner': 2, 'balance': 1000, 'report_date': datetime.date(2023, 2, 2)}, {'owner': 2, 'balance': 2000, 'report_date': datetime.date(2023, 2, 22)}]>
```

a simple group by `owner` and aggregating the minimum of `report_date` will be as follows,

```py
Report.objects.values('owner').annotate(min_report_date=Min('report_date')).values('owner', 'min_report_date')
```

and the result will be as follows,

```py
<QuerySet [{'owner': 1, 'min_report_date': datetime.date(2023, 3, 4)}, {'owner': 2, 'min_report_date': datetime.date(2023, 2, 2)}]>
```

Now I want to return the `balance` corresponding to the minimum of `report_date` field in addition to the `owner` and `min_report_date` fields like bellow,

```py
<QuerySet [{'owner': 1, 'min_report_date': datetime.date(2023, 3, 4), 'balance': 100}, {'owner': 2, 'min_report_date': datetime.date(2023, 2, 2), 'balance': 1000}]>
```

---

My attempt was the bellow Django query,

```py
Report.objects.values('owner').annotate(min_report_date=Min('report_date')).values('owner', 'min_report_date', 'balance')
```

but the result lost the effect of aggregation (i.e., all rows were returned) and was like bellow,

```py
 <QuerySet [{'owner': 1, 'balance': 50, 'min_report_date': datetime.date(2023, 3, 9)}, {'owner': 1, 'balance': 100, 'min_report_date': datetime.date(2023, 3, 4)}, {'owner': 2, 'balance': 2000, 'min_report_date': datetime.date(2023, 2, 22)}, {'owner': 2, 'balance': 1000, 'min_report_date': datetime.date(2023, 2, 2)}]>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with a [**`Subquery`** expression <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

Owner.objects.annotate(
    min_report_balance=Subquery(
        Report.objects.filter(owner_id=OuterRef('pk'))
        .order_by('report_date')
        .values('balance')[:1]
    )
)
```

The `Owner` objects that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `min_report_balance` that is the `balance` of the "oldest" `Report` for that owner, or `None` (`NULL`) in case no such report exists.